# How do I create a drop down menu with a list of check boxes with labels using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have found a few tutorials that explain this in one form or another. Most don't implement it with bootstrap, and the ones that do tend to be a few years old.

I am unsure where to even start with this.

My app is using AngularJS on the client, if that matters.

Edit: Here's one of the tutorials I am talking about. http://www.benknowscode.com/2014/09/option-picker-bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox.html

Answer (score 1):

On this link you can find a working example:

http://codepen.io/bseth99/pen/fboKH

HTML:

```
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 6</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var options = [];

$( '.dropdown-menu a' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

   var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
       val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
       $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
       idx;

   if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
      options.splice( idx, 1 );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
   } else {
      options.push( val );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
   }

   $( event.target ).blur();

   console.log( options );
   return false;
});
```